# Configuring PostGis on Dreamhost

Tags: installation, postgis, dreamhost

I've installed PostGIS on my Dreamhost hosted VPS and have gotten to the configure section of the process as detailed here: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#installation_configuration

In the last line when I run ./configure I get this error:

```
configure: error: could not find pg_config within the current 
path. You may need to try re-running configure with a --with-pgconfig parameter.
```

And I see in the instructions say:

```
--with-pgconfig=FILE
```

PostgreSQL provides a utility called pg_config to enable extensions like PostGIS to locate the PostgreSQL installation directory. Use this parameter (--with-pgconfig=/path/to/pg_config) to manually specify a particular PostgreSQL installation that PostGIS will build against.

However, I can't find a way to find where this file is. I know I have PostGre installed because it says so when I run this:

```
aptitude show postgresql | grep State
```

coming back with

```
State: installed
```

But I don't know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to also install the "dev" package for PostgreSQL. For example, with Debian 6.0 (squeeze) this package is called [`postgresql-server-dev-8.4`](http://packages.debian.org/stable/database/postgresql-server-dev-8.4). It will give you `pg_config` to configure PostGIS.

[Look here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall) for simple install instructions for various versions of PostGIS on various Linux distros.

Comment: Thank you! That was so much simpler than "easy" package and/or graphical installs

Comment: And, of course, the moment I say that and try a check it gives me an error. `WARNING:

configure was unable to find CUnit which is required for unit testing.
In order to enable unit testing, you must install CUnit and then re-run configure.` Trying to find info on CUnit on the PostGIS site but not finding it...

Comment: And this error as well `Something went wrong during db initialization (core module).
 For details, check /tmp/pgis_reg/regress_log

dropdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "username"
make[1]: *** [check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/username/postgis-2.0.0/regress'
make: *** [check] Error 1'`

Comment: Install the package `libcunit1-dev` for your first issue. To do the tests, you need to add your username as a PostgreSQL user too, you can do this in pgAdminIII.